# What is the best way to store password parameters in Jenkins?

Tags: security, jenkins, devops

I wonder what is the best practice way to store password parameters in Jenkins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to store them as Jenkins Credentials and inject them into your build via CredentialsBinding Plugin, whereby you can define how to make them available via the environment (Username:Password, Separated Username and Password,...). Jenkins supports different types of credentials such as

- Username and Password
- SSH Keys
- Docker Credentials
- ...

This way the credentials are only visible to the build execution and cannot be accessed by other developers, just used. Jenkins will hide exact matches of the username and password in the logs.

### Links

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Binding+Plugin